# maximum of a holomorphic function over a compact subset of a bounded region

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

If $\Omega$ is a bounded region in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega$ is connected and $K$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$, show that $\hat{K}_{\Omega} = \hat{K}_{\mathbb{C}}$. ($\hat{K}_{\Omega} = \{z \in \Omega|\quad |f(z)| \leq \max_{\zeta \in K}{|f(\zeta)|, \forall f \in H(\Omega)} \}$ and $H(\Omega)$ denotes the space of analytic functions on $\Omega$.)

**My thoughts:**

Since $\mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega$ is connected, hence $\Omega$ is simply connected and bounded. WLOG, we can assume $\Omega$ is the open unit disk and $K$ is any compact subset $\{|z| \leq r, 0<r<1\}$. This means I need to show that for any point, $z_0$ outside the unit disk, $|f(z_0)|> \max_{\zeta \in K}|f(\zeta|$. Probably, I also need to use the fact that any analytic function in $K$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials , according to Mergelyan's theorem. But I am not able to put all this together to form a coherent argument. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear that you can assume that $\Omega$ is the unit disk, since the biholomorphic mapping between $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{D}$ generally doesn't extend beyond the two domains, so composing an entire function with the biholomorphism need not lead to an entire function again, and hence it is not clear that the polynomially convex hulls correspond to each other.

However, Runge's approximation theorem makes things easy. Every $f \in H(\Omega)$ is the locally uniform limit of rational functions whose poles lie outside $\Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is simply connected, we have the even better

> Every $f \in H(\Omega)$ is the locally uniform limit of polynomials.

Since generally

$$\hat{K}_\Omega \subset \hat{K}_\mathbb{C}$$

is clear, all that remains is to show the reverse inclusion.

Consider a $z \in \Omega \setminus \hat{K}_\Omega$, and an $f \in H(\Omega)$ with $\lvert f(z)\rvert > \max \{ \lvert f(\zeta)\rvert : \zeta \in K\}$.

Throw Runge on it to see that $z \notin \hat{K}_\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Isn't it true that if $|f(z)|> \max\{|f(\zeta)|:\zeta \in K\}$, then $z \not \in \hat{K}_U$ for any open set $U$.? I am sorry I am just not getting the objective of this problem.

Comment: The subscript indicates which set of functions is considered for the hull. $\hat{K}_\Omega=\{z:\bigl(\forall f\in H(\Omega)\bigr)(\lvert f(z)\rvert\leqslant\lVert f\rVert_K\}$, and $\hat{K}_\mathbb{C}=\{z:\bigl(\forall f\in H(\mathbb{C})\bigr)(\lvert f(z)\rvert\leqslant\lVert f\rVert_K\}$. It is easily possible that in a point all entire functions attain a value whose modulus is not larger than the largest modulus attained on $K$, but some functions that are holomorphic in $\Omega$ attain a value of greater magnitude there. Consider $K=\{\lvert z\rvert = 1\}$ in $0 < \lvert z\rvert < 2$.

Comment: $\hat{K}_{\mathbb{C}} = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1\}$ then, but $\hat{K}_\Omega = K$. The point is that this does not happen if $\Omega$ is simply connected.

Comment: I did not notice the difference between the set of functions considered for $K_C$ and $K_\Omega$. Thank you.

Comment: I fear this might be another elementary question, but isn't $H(\mathbb{C}) \subset H(\Omega)$? If that is true then, how is $\hat{K}_{\Omega} \subset \hat{K}_C$ generally true? Why can't it be that $z \in \Omega\setminus K$ such that $z \in \hat{K}_{\Omega}$, but $z \not \in \hat{K}_{\mathbb{C}}$ ?

Comment: Yes, $H(\mathbb{C})\subset H(\Omega)$ (well, the pedant in me feels urged to point out that technically, it's not a subset, the restriction gives a natural injection; but one very rarely needs to be so pedantic). And that's why always $\hat{K}_\Omega\subset\hat{K}_\mathbb{C}$. It's probably clearest to see if we take another step on the abstraction ladder, let $\mathscr{F}$ be a family of functions defined (at least) on $\Omega$. The $\mathscr{F}$-convex hull of $K$ is$$\hat{K}_\mathscr{F} = \bigcap_{f\in\mathscr{F}} f^{-1}(D(f,K)),$$where $D(f,K)=\{z:\lvert z\rvert\leqslant\lVert f\rVert_K\}$

Comment: Since $D(f,K)$ and hence $f^{-1}(D(f,K))$ doesn't depend on $\mathscr{F}$, it is then clear that $$\mathscr{F}_1 \subset \mathscr{F}_2 \Rightarrow \hat{K}_{\mathscr{F}_2} \subset \hat{K}_{\mathscr{F}_1},$$ and since $H(\mathbb{C})\subset H(\Omega)$, we have $\hat{K}_{H(\Omega)} \subset \hat{K}_{H(\mathbb{C})}$. Thue used notation writes $\hat{K}_U$ instead of $\hat{K}_{H(U)}$, since only holomorphic functions are ever considered.